# AREA tag's offsetLeft and offsetTop values work in IE, but appear broken in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, imagemap

I have a simple image map:

```
<img alt="Image" src="./TestImage.jpg" usemap="#myMap" />
<map name="myMap" id="myMap">
    <area id="Fox" alt="Fox" shape="rect" coords="344,0,530,170" />
    <area id="Grass" alt="Grass" shape="rect" coords="80,160,250,280" />
</map>
```

I use jQuery to attach a mouseover event handler:

```
$(window).load(function () {
$('div map area').mouseover(function (e) {
    ...
}
```

I examine the element's offset:

```
var offset = $(this).offset();
```

When I hover over the Fox AREA, I see the following:

- IE returns the correct values: (344, 0)
- Chrome tells me the offset is (0,0)
- Firefox tells me the offset is (8, 76,8333...)

Why are Chrome and Firefox returning incorrect values and is there anything I can do to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch the "coords" attribute directly:

```
var coords = $(this).attr('coords').split(',');
```

Comment: Thank you - this has been driving me nuts!

Comment: I've looked for an answer to why the browsers differ so much but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Sorry - I clearly didn't have my thinking head on earlier. Yes, I *COULD* split the coords, but if the area is a poly, then I have to iterate each point and build the bounding box. This is what I'd expect offset left, top, width and height should give me. I've filed bugs with Chrome and Firefox as both get it wrong :(

Comment: Yes that's true.  It's weird, but I can't find any spec that says it *should* work the way your code expects. I mean, it makes perfect sense that it would, but FF and Chrome are giving such bizarre answers that it seems like they had some entirely different idea about the semantics.

Comment: I filed a bug for this against both Chrome and Firefox. The FF team have stated that the spec is unclear on this. The Chrome team have yet to respond. Next, I'll be trying to file a bug against the HTML5 spec. Wish me luck ;)

Comment: Pointy - excellent workaround. Simple yet 100% transparent to the developer. Sometimes the easy answer is right under our noses. Well done.